# Android Studio 2.2 doesn't package third party library to apk

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

I use Android Studio 2.2's `cmake` to build native code, in the native code I invoked the ffmpeg api, so the ffmpeg library should be packaged. My `CMakelists.txt` is as below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
include_directories(libs/arm/include)
link_directories(libs/arm/lib/)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             # Associated headers in the same location as their source
             # file are automatically included.
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )


find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
add_library(avcodec-57 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avcodec-57 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION C:/Users/tony/Desktop/MyApplication/app/libs/arm/lib/libavcodec-57.so)
target_link_libraries(native-lib avcodec-57)
target_link_libraries(native-lib avformat-57)

target_link_libraries(native-lib avutil-55)
target_link_libraries(native-lib avfilter-6)
```

In such case, I can make project successfully, but when I install the apk to emulator and run, it failed and show that "libavcodec-57.so" isn't found.
Then I use tool (analyze apk) to check the apk, found that the ffmpeg library isn't packaged.

Comment: We have the same issue. After further investigations we found out that no static or shared libraries were found at all. You could test it by using "find_library" and direct path search.

Comment: I use  find_library(avcodec-lib NAMES avcodec-57  HINTS C:/Users/tony/Desktop/MyApplication/app/libs/armeabi/lib/) but failed.

Comment: Just we canceled further investigations because it seems to be an Android Studio related issue. I found https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211927.

Comment: You could try as reported in the issue 211927 and bypass the parameters. E.g. find_library(avcodec-lib NAMES avcodec-57 HINTS C:/Users/tony/Desktop/MyApplication/app/libs/armeabi/lib/ CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_BOTH NO_DEFAULT_PATH)  but for us also that was not working. We will switch now to the old approach using Android.mk and Application.mk

Comment: it still can't work.Maybe I only switch to old approach.

Comment: IMPORTED shared lib is not automatically packed into the final APK, it is more or less a bug.  But for now your app will need to pack all of the dependent shared libs yourself:  hello-libs [https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-libs/app/build.gradle] does that with playing jniLibs to get libgerf.so packed. That usage model is very similar to yours here [ your lib is also pre-built somewhere else ].

Answer (score 3):

I found a way that works for me, not sure it helps you but it might. I'm using Android Studio 2.2, and ran into your problem too.

I created a jar-file, with the prebuilt libraries in it:

```
lib
--|armeabi
--|--|libMyLIb.so
etc.
```

by simply creating a folder lib with that contents somewhere, and the executing the command

```
zip -r myjar.zip lib && mv myjar.zip myjar.jar
```

Next, I put the jar file in here:

```
app/libs/myjar.jar
```

And added these lines to the CMakeLists.txt that builds a native .so-library inside Android Studio. That is, I started with an empty project off the template for calls to native code (the default libnative-lib.so):

```
# already there:
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   native-lib

                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${log-lib} )

# my addition:
add_custom_command(TARGET native-lib POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs"
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:native-lib>)
```

And magically, now if I build the apk, the contents of my jar end up in the final apk. Don't ask me why this works, really, I have no clue, it was accidental.

What this means for me, is that I compile the empty libnative-lib.so, for the only purpose of tricking Android Studio into including my jar.

Perhaps someone finds a cleaner solution, and can point out where my solution is a ridiculous loop that resulted out of misunderstanding gradle and cmake...

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem.
Cmake does not automatically pack third library into the apk , you have to do it yourself.

Here is an exemple with libavcodec and libavutil from ffmpeg.

1- Copy your pre-built lib into app/libs/[abi]/
Exemple : `app/libs/armeabi-v7a/libavcodec.so`

2- Copy include into app/libs/include

Then in your cmakelist.txt add the libraries you need

```
find_library( log-lib log )
set(ffmpeg_DIR ../../../../libs) #set path to libs folder

add_library( libavutil SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( libavutil PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${ffmpeg_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libavutil.so )

add_library( libavcodec SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( libavcodec PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${ffmpeg_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libavcodec.so )

include_directories(libs/include) #add include dir. don't know  why ../ not needed

add_library( native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

target_link_libraries( native-lib libavcodec libavutil ${log-lib} )
```

Finally in your build.gradle set jniLibsfolder :

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
}
```

Setting jniLibs.srcDir was the key for me to be able to bundle the libs into the apk.

Note that i used libs folder but you can probably use any folder you want to store your pre-built libs.

Found a working sample on github (not mine) : https://github.com/imchenjianneng/StudyTestCase

Answer (score 2):

I suffered the same problem.
Gradle doesn't packaging .so files into apk while I filled CMakeLists.txt correctly, but finally I resolved it.

Add the JniLibs path into sourceSets in local build.gradle as this sample code:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-libs/app/build.gradle
which is [@Gerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4496512/gerry) mentioned in the comment.

I did:

---

1. copy .so libraries into src/main/JniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}.

   ex) mobile/src/main/JniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libavcodec.so

---

2. edit CMakeLists.txt

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# project path (absolute), change it to yours.
set(projectDir C:/Users/Administrator/AndroidStudioProjects/TestApp1)

# headers
include_directories(${projectDir}/mobile/src/main/JniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/include)

# sample ndk lib
add_library( native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

# FFMPEG libraries
add_library( lib_avcodec SHARED IMPORTED )

set_target_properties(  lib_avcodec  PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION  ${projectDir}/mobile/src/main/JniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libavcodec.so)

# ...
# (omitted) same codes with lib_avdevice, lib_avfilter, lib_avformat, lib_avutil, lib_swresample, and lib_swscale each.
# ...

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   native-lib

                   lib_avcodec
                   lib_avdevice
                   lib_avfilter
                   lib_avformat
                   lib_avutil
                   lib_swresample
                   lib_swscale
                   )
```

---

3. in build.gradle (app)

build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your-application-Id"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            // Specifies the ABI configurations of your native
            // libraries Gradle should build and package with your APK.
            abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    # ADD THIS BLOCK.
    sourceSets {
        main {
            // let gradle pack the shared library into apk
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/JniLibs']
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

---

hope it helps you.

p.s. I used FFMPEG libraries that built myself.